# Alpha channel in C++Builder

Tags: animation, c++builder, alpha, vcl

In Borland/Embarcadero C++Builder with VCL, I am trying to develop an application with an image where some parts (in fact, circles) fade in or out over time.

My code is mostly as follows:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfmMain::FormCreate(TOBject *Sender)
{
    img = new TBitmap;
    img->Width = 800;
    img->Height = 600;
    fmMain->DoubleBuffered = true;
    ...
}

void __fastcall TfmMain::tmMainTimer(TObject *Sender)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nbParts; i++){
        ...
        img->Brush->Color = clRed | alpha (t_time) << 24;
        //   alpha is a function returning 0 to 0xff, depending on required level of fade at time t_time) 
        img->Canvas->Ellipse(....);
    }
    fmMain->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, img);
}
```

But the result is not at all what I want : as an example, a part supposed to fade out has its color alternating between red and black. Same for a part supposed to fade in.

I tried `DrawTransparent()`, but had the error:

> DrawTransparent is not accessible

And it has a transparency value for the whole bitmap, not for individual parts.

I tried a separate bitmap for each part, but I may have hundreds of them, and the animation becomes too slow.

Please, can someone help, and tell me what I should do?

Comment: `TCanvas` does not support drawing with `TColor` values that have an alpha specified. You will have to manipulate the bitmap's raw pixel bytes directly, via the `TBitmap.Scanline` property.  Make sure you set the `TBitmap.PixelFormat` property to `pf32bit` to create room for an alpha channel, and also set the `TBitmap.AlphaFormat` property as needed.

Comment: And before you wonder why TCanvas does not support such a common feature: this is because it is based on GDI which does not support alpha either.

Comment: Thanks for this. Still , I am missing something : I wrote a small program as a test, and the result is that alpha channel=0 gives a white color, =0xff gives the desired color (red), and values inbetween a corresponding mix of white and red. But it does not modify the transparency, the background is always hidden. Or is it because I use "imDraw->Picture->Bitmap=bm1" to transfer my bitmap (bm1) to a TImage on the main form ? If so, what coud I use ? AlphaBlend does not exist in Borland/Embarcadero C++, nor Windows::AlphaBlend.